# Python type hints: List of allowed objects (not literals)

Tags: python, type-hinting

Say I have a function `foo(f)` where `f` should be one of `np.sin` or `np.cos`. What would be the correct way to type hint this?

```py
import numpy as np
def foo(f: Literal[np.sin, np.cos]):
    ...
```

looks about right, but `np.sin` and `np.cos` are not in fact literals, so my linter complains.

Comment: `float` or `list` with a `docstring` describing the arguments.

Comment: What are the `np.sin` and `np.cos`?

Comment: `numpy.float64`

Comment: @YuriiMotov Sorry, shouldn't have assumed numpy to be obvious.. They're functions (the sine and tho cosine function, but only as an example here).

Comment: @D.L Well, they're `np.ufunc`, but I guess your comment still translates to "No way of doing this in the type hint, do it in the docstring"?

Comment: well, you could then use `np.ufunc`. i also updated the answer to include this. Good question BTW.

Answer (score 2):

As the official documentation says, `sin` and `cos` are numpy functions (official doc: [sin](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sin.html#numpy.sin) and [cos](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cos.html#numpy.cos)). So you can't use `Literal` because is conceptually incorrect.

In my opinion, without going to deepen every type of function, you can use `type` function (`builtins`) and if you want to be restrictive, use `assert`:

```
def foo(f: type(np.sin) | type(np.cos)):
    assert f == np.sin or f == np.cos, f"Expected {np.sin} or {np.cos}, got {f}"
    # ...
```

Or, if you know the data structure of the functions you are using, you can use `ufunc` directly:

```
def foo(f: np.ufunc):
    assert f == np.sin or f == np.cos, f"Expected {np.sin} or {np.cos}, got {f}"
    # ...
```

As [B Remmelzwaal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17200348/b-remmelzwaal) mentions in the comment, if you run a script with debugging off, `assert` won't be executed, so he recommends using it:

```
def foo(f: np.ufunc):
    expected_types = [np.sin, np.cos]
    if f not in expected_types:
        raise ValueError(f"Expected {expected_types} got {f}")
    # ...
```

Comment: `type(...)` is invalid as a type.

Comment: `assert` won't be run when running a script with debugging off, so I would recommend using `if f not in [np.sin, np.cos]: raise ValueError(...)`.

Comment: @B Remmelzwaal Good point. I have edited my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That would be an abuse of typing. Typing applied to a function describes whether the called function will behave correctly, wheras this sort of restriction usually is about whether the unit calling the function is obeying a business rule.

Either:

- the `foo` function compares the value of `f` with the values `np.sin` and `np.cos` and misbehaves otherwise. In this case you have an ad-hoc enumeration which is coupled to another module, and although there are reasons for doing that (e.g. `print ('sinus' if f is np.sin else 'cosinus')` ), the intent usually can be expressed better by either using an enum or by encapsulating it in an object.
- the `foo` function only uses the `f` argument as a numpy function. In this case, it is unlikely that the function is unsafe if a different numpy function were to be passed in; you then have an arbitrary restriction that does not increase safety of the program, which is pointless.

Comment: Why would it be an abuse of typing? I mean, obviously `Literal` is wrong here, but if `Literal['a', 'b']` is fine rather than the alternatives you outline (i.e. `str` with checks in the function or an enum), why would something equivalent for these objects be abusive?

Comment: @schtandard `Literal['a']` does not create a coupling to another module, and is acting as an ad-hoc enumeration, e.g. for `open()` mode. Though even in that case, the intent would be better expressed as enum flags instead, as the 'stringiness' of the argument is irrelevant to the behaviour.

Comment: Hmm, your second point I see. Regarding the first one: So if I defined `sin()` and `cos()` myself, you wouldn't consider a type hint like I intend abusive?

Comment: @schtandard I would still wonder why you had code that depended on the identity of the functions rather than their behaviour. If you want to combine identity and behaviour, then usually you use a class for that, not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Is this approach suitable for you?

```
def foo(f: Literal["np.sin", "np.cos"]):
    return getattr(np, f.removeprefix("np."))()

print(foo("np.cos"))

print(foo("np.sin"))
```

or this:

```
import numpy as np
def _foo(f: np.ufunc):
    ...

def foo_sin():
    return _foo(np.sin)

def foo_cos():
    return _foo(np.cos)
```

Comment: While this does work, I don't want to change the function signature to match what can be done with type hints. If it can't be done, then so be it.

Comment: And how about just creating two separate functions `foo_sin` and `foo_cos`?

Comment: I can see that this would be a good solution in some cases, but in my particular one, I prefer to just describe it in the docstring. The existence of `Literal` made me expect that there is a way to do it in the type hints, but if there isn't, that's not a huge deal.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't allow arbitrary literal objects. As [outlined in PEP 586](https://peps.python.org/pep-0586/#legal-parameters-for-literal-at-type-check-time):

> `Literal` may be parameterized with literal ints, byte and unicode strings, bools, Enum values and `None`.

Note the mention of Enum values, which can be a useful workaround (if not a bit more verbose) for specifying arbitrary literals. In your case, you can do the following:

```py
import typing as t
import enum
import numpy as np

class np_funcs(enum.Enum):
    sin = np.sin
    cos = np.cos
    tan = np.tan

def foo(f: t.Literal[np_funcs.sin, np_funcs.cos]):
    # You'll have to access the underlying function using the `.value` attribute of the
    # enum member
    return f.value(0)
```

```
>>> foo(np_funcs.cos)  # OK
>>> foo(np_funcs.tan)  # mypy: Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "Literal[np_funcs.tan]"; expected "Literal[np_funcs.sin, np_funcs.cos]"  [arg-type]
```

Answer (score -2):

I would say `np.float64` is the correct type. and the reason for this is that this is what both of these functions return.

You can check the types like this:

```py
import numpy as np


x = np.sin(100)
print(type(x))
```

which both return:

```
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

so the function should look like this:

```py
def foo(f: np.float64):
    ''' takes in a numpy sin or cos and does something 
    
    args:
        f: numpy sin or cos

    retrurn:
        something
    
    '''
    
    return
```

but as per the comments, you could also use `np.ufunc` if you want the actual functions themselves then it would be this:

```py
def foo(f: np.ufunc):
    ''' takes in a numpy sin or cos and does something 
    
    args:
        f: numpy sin or cos

    retrurn:
        something
    
    '''
    
    return


foo(100)
```

Comment: Well, they're `np.ufunc`, not `np.float64` (check `type(np.sin)`), but I guess your answer still translates to "No way of doing this in the type hint, do it in the docstring"?

Comment: i actually added `np.ufunc` too (which also works).   so now you can pick both...

Comment: But, yes, i would be inclined to use the doc string too. I find type hinting for complex things like this very useful, so it is a good question.